# Scala - Case Sequence

Tags: scala

I just read about case sequence as partial functions and the syntax is a little bit strange.

For example

```
def test: Int => Int = {
  case 1 => 2
  case 2 => 3
  case _ => 0
}
```

I would expect that `test` has no arguments and would return a function of type `Int => Int`

But after some testing it seems that it takes an int as an argument and returns an int, so I rewrote it to...

```
def test1(i: Int): Int =
  i match {
    case 1 => 2
    case 2 => 3
    case _ => 0
  }
```

Are `test` and `test1` equal?

Comment: what kind of testing did you do that lead you to conclude they are equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former code does return a function of type Int => Int.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def test: Int => Int = {
case 1 => 2
case 2 => 3
case _ => 0
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

test: Int => Int

scala> test
res0: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> test.apply(1)
res1: Int = 2
```

Perhaps what is confusing is that apply can be called directly:

```
scala> test(1)
res2: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 6):

They are not equal. `test` is a method that returns a `Function1[Int,Int]` and `test1` is a method that takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`. This is also completely unrelated to the pattern matching expression.

Answer (score 0):

test is a function of type "Int => Int"
test1 is a method that uses a partial function (the match expression) internally. 
So they are not equal.

If you want to check Types use the REPL:

```
:type test
Int => Int

:type test1 _
Int => Int
```